# Restrict controller hit from view using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to do one validation for already exists or not. If the value exists, even the button click happened it should not go to the controller hit. My view is designed begin form and submit type. So without ajax call it is automatically goes to the controller. I done the changes like below, but no hope

**In View**

```
<td align="left"><button type="submit" id="btnOK" class="btn btn-success" name="command" onclick="return checkExists(this);" value="ok" disabled="disabled">OK</button></td>
```

I have added one method `checkExists`. i take tabNameList (already exists in the db) values and comparing those things then call `e.preventDefault()`

```
 function checkExists(e)
    {
        debugger;
        var headerName = $("#strTabHeader").val();
        $.each(tabNameList, function (index, item) {
            if(item==headerName)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
//return false;
            }            
        });
     }
```

But it is not working. Kindly suggest me. I really stuck here long time.

Comment: Do I get your question right - you want to disable the form from submitting when hitting the button? In that case you need to use the submit event from the form, not the click event from the button.

Answer (score 0):

Better stop event click and check condition like this:

```
<td align="left"><button type="submit" id="btnOK" class="btn btn-success" name="command" value="ok" disabled="disabled">OK</button></td>

$('#btnOK').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var headerName = $("#strTabHeader").val();
    $.each(tabNameList, function (index, item) {
        if(item!=headerName)
        {
            //submit form
            $('form').submit();

        } 
    });
})
```